# debugging java vacation program

Tags: java

Thank you for viewing my post and any contributions to my program. Can someone help me with debugging this java program please. I found the bugs in the main method but cannot point out the bug in the other methods.

```
   // A Vaction is 10 days
// but an ExtendedVacation is 30 days
public class testclass1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
          DebugVacation myVacation = new DebugVacation(int days);

          DebugExtendedVacation yourVacation = new DebugExtendedVacation(int days);

          System.out.println("My vacation is for " +
             myVacation.getDays() + " days");

          System.out.println("Your vacation is for " +
             yourVacation.getDays() + " days");
        }
}

//_____________________________________


class DebugExtendedVacation extends DebugVacation
{
  public DebugExtendedVacation(int days)
  {
      super(days);
          days = 30;
  }

  public int getDays()
  {
        super.getDays();
        return days;

  }
}

//______________________

class DebugVacation
{
  public int days = 10;

  public DebugVacation(int days)
  {
     this.days = days;
  }
  public int getDays()
  {
          return days;
  }
}
```

Comment: According to my IDE it is something in my vacation method

Comment: your missing `()` on `myVacation.getDays`

Comment: i fixed the () on myVacation.getDays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DebugVacation` and `DebugExtendedVacation` constructors require an `int` parameter.

You must create objects like this:

```
DebugVacation myVacation = new DebugVacation(10);

DebugExtendedVacation yourVacation = new DebugExtendedVacation(10);
```

This is how your program must be:

```
// A Vaction is 10 days
// but an ExtendedVacation is 30 days
public class testclass1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
          // Declaration must be done here.
          int days = 10; // Or any other value.


          // Then you simply pass the value of the variable as a parameter here.
          DebugVacation myVacation = new DebugVacation(days);

          DebugExtendedVacation yourVacation = new DebugExtendedVacation(days);

          System.out.println("My vacation is for " +
             myVacation.getDays() + " days");

          System.out.println("Your vacation is for " +
             yourVacation.getDays() + " days");
    }
}

//_____________________________________


class DebugExtendedVacation extends DebugVacation
{
  public DebugExtendedVacation(int days)
  {
      super(days);
          days = 30;
  }

  public int getDays()
  {
        super.getDays();
        return days;

  }
}

//______________________

class DebugVacation
{
  public int days = 10;

  public DebugVacation(int days)
  {
     this.days = days;
  }
  public int getDays()
  {
          return days;
  }
}
```

Comment: should it be int days;

Comment: exactly. yes. you need to pass an integer.

Comment: in the main or the other methods

Comment: Anywhere you create objects for `DebugVacation` and `DebugExtendedVacation`

Comment: No no no no no. It seems you are new to Java. I will edit my answer and write the whole program for you.

Comment: Thank you yes i am fairly new to java

Comment: Well, if the code worked for you, please accept the answer. :))

Comment: Coud you debug another program for me

Comment: Sure. But you gotta ask that as a separate question. Don't mix it in here in the same question. Keep all your questions separate. And just post the link of the page containing your question here in the comment.

Comment: but i guess i can only post every 90 minutes

Comment: is there another way you can help me?

Comment: No. You must wait for the time being then. And it has always been a problem with new java programmers that they do not read the error generated. You must read the whole error line by line as a beginner. Do you know? Reading and understanding the error generated is always an essential part for programming. Half of the error solves when one simple reads and understands what the error is.

Comment: i am getting the wrong result. i get extended is supposed to be 30 and vacation is supposed to be 10

Comment: Yeah thats what you get here.